# How to find number of a certain character from file in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file, scanf

I'm trying to find out the number of times a letter (say, the letter "b") occurs in paragraph from a file.  I'm trying to use arrays to count them, but I'm not sure about how to use the if-else statements properly.

So far all I can do is:

```
 int main(void)
{
    FILE *fin = fopen("paragraph.txt", "r");
    FILE *fout = fopen("number_of_times_bandc_occurs.txt", "w");
    char line[]='\0';
    int b=0; int c=0;

    while(fscanf("%d", &line) != EOF)
    {
        //Using the if-else statements here is where I'm having difficulty.
    }

    fclose(fout);
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}
```

Btw, I'm kind of a beginner...so I might need some extra explaining.
I should also mention that the paragraph has multiple lines of text.

Comment: this line: while(fscanf("%d", &line) != EOF) should be: while((ch = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) // where ch is defined as int ch;  Then if( 'b' == (char)ch )  {b_count++;} // where count is defined as int or long long int and initialized to 0  if( 'c' == (char)ch ) {c_count++;}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** I misread you question. To count a specific character you should do something like this:

```
int ch, countB = 0, countC = 0;
while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
   if(ch == 'B')
      countB++;
   if(ch == 'C')
      countC++;
}
```

Comment: But `tbl` should be an array of unsigned, e.g. declared as `unsigned tbl[256+1] = {0};` because a given letter (e.g. `e`) could have more than 256 occurrences!

Comment: Not fixed, it is still an array of `unsigned char`. You could have 1000 or even 1000000 occurrences of `e`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: You're right and I get your point but as I had misunderstood the question I've removed this approach from my answer and updated with the right one.

Comment: the question was for B and C, capitalized, not lower case, and a sep counter for the Bs and for the Cs.

Comment: This code example was supposed to demostre how to count a specific character, by edited anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
int count=0;
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) 
{
    if (ch == 'b')
    {
        count++;
    }
}
//Then print count
```

Or

```
char line[256];
int count=0, i;
char *p;
size_t length;
while(fgets(line, 256, fin))
{
    if ((p=strchr(line, '\n')) != NULL)
        *p = '\0';
    length = strlen(line); //For using strlen() include <string.h>
    for(i=0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(line[i] == 'b')
            count++;
    }   
}
//Then print count
```

Comment: @Smac89: Reading file using `fscanf` in this case is not a good idea. So I removed the code and use `fgets`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this simple code patch

```
long ch_occ[26] = {0};
char ch;
while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
   if(ch == 'a')
      ++ch_occ[0];
else if(ch == 'b')
      ++ch_occ[1];
else if(ch == 'c')
      ++ch_occ[2];
.
.

//Similarly you can create for all 26 alphabets;
//then the first index of array ch_occ will have occurrences of 'a' and next index will have of 'b' and so on...
```

}

Comment: You can avoid writing out the condition so many times by assuming 'not EBCDIC' (so no gaps in the code points for the alphabet), then you can use `if (islower(ch)) ++ch_occ[ch - 'a'];` as the entire body of the loop.

Comment: This is wrong on two points.  1) the op is only interested in B and C, and two the suggested code would require 256 sets of if... else if ..,

Comment: In above question B and C is Just an example quoted it does not restrict the scope of question. Secondly as the question states the occurrences of letters(like a,b,c etc) not characters so the conditions required would be 26 in case of case insensitive count and 52 for case sensitive.